# How to add font-family in app_offline.htm page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need to add custom content in app_offline.htm page and want that font should be similar in overall application. Currently I am using Soleil font but if I try to access it from fonts folder, it would obviously won't work, so I am now stuck. Can anyone please suggest how can I use it in app_offline.htm page?